# Is there a way with Roslyn to bundle all dependencies with the generated app

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, bundle, roslyn

I've recently started working with Roslyn for building apps at runtime.

After a few hours, I've finally managed to compile a working executable of a console application which only does:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello World, Roslyn");
```

The main issue I've faced was how to add the reference to the System namespace. Finally I've used the following line, chained with the creation of the CSharpCompilation object:

```cs
.AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
```

It works perfectly but when I try and debug this, I found that:

```cs
typeof(object).Assembly.Location
```

returns:

> "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"

I am worried that this path may vary depending on the machine. Thus, I was wondering if there was a way to bundle all the dependencies next to the generated .exe? (like if you were to build a self-contained .Net Core app).